# Maximum Disk Space supported by Marklogic 8

Tags: marklogic, diskspace

we are aiming to extend the disk space of our Marklogic 8 Database to 35TB, I wonder if there is any limitation for max disk space for Marklogic 8?

Comment: How many hosts are you talking about? And how many forests per host do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic will support [Petabytes of data](https://www.marklogic.com/blog/scaling-to-olympic-proportions/), so 35 TB is not a problem, assuming you have enough computing power and RAM to support the number of forests that you have.  Although it depends greatly on your individual application, a general rule of thumb is 2 threads (or vCores) per forest, and 4Gb RAM per thread/vCore.

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, I wonder is there a (theoretical) max limit of disk space that Marklogic can support?

Comment: @HopeHou I'm not sure. I've not yet been able to track that information down.